# Draft.js / Rails Setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, draftjs

Is it possible to use DraftJs with a Rails framework ?

> Currently using the following GEMs:
>
> > 1. gem 'js-routes'
> > 2. gem 'react-rails', '1.6.1'
> > 3. gem 'rails-assets-classnames'

On rails-assets, cannot find anything related to Draft.Js.

I would prefer not using npm (which seems to be required).

Comment: that is the only way, using npm and you can use the compiled files.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Any good links / tutorial to share on how to install & use npm on a rails framework? so hard to find... best!

Comment: btw, if you're struggling getting your draft.js app hooked up with a server you should check out this tutorial on how to do draft-js <> server interaction https://reactrocket.com/post/draft-js-persisting-content/